# How long do I have to stay outside of the Schengen Area?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, visa-free-entry

I was in Germany and Switzerland for 90 days in total. I'm a US citizen just traveling and looking to pick up work and perhaps, find real employment. How long must I wait before I can legally re-enter into the Schengen countries?

Answer (score 2):

You must stay out for 90 days, as you're allowed to stay for 90 days in a 180-day period.

Bear in mind, if you do find yourself a job and decide to move there, for most countries you'll have to go back home and apply for a Long-stay visa, then re-enter and obtain a residence permit. However, Germany, for example, does let Americans apply for a residence permit during a visa-free visit.

Comment: And as an US citizen you can not have casual work, not legally and if found out doing it illegally you will not be able to come back for a job with a work permit.

Answer (score 2):

You must use so called 90/180 rule: 90 days within 180 days, so if you've stayed the full 90 days in the Schengen zone, you must wait for 90 days before you are allowed to re-enter the Schengen zone visa free.